# FIX protocol implementation

Tags: xml, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I'm writing a FIXEngine using Quickfix/N to receive ExecutionReport of our trading activity.
Our counterparty doesn't provide us with any FIXML specification. That means that I only have a pdf document with a list of fields (without even their type).

So I have to create by hand the FIX.xml dictionary following the document.

I wanted to know if:

- It is normal that the counterparty doesn't provide any FIXML or at
  least a XSD to be sure to comply with their specification of the
  protocol?

  Also, it happen that the list of fields used by the couterpaty is a
  subset of the entire list of fields specified by the standard. In
  this case, should I only define the used fields and messages in the
  XML  or should I always use the  standard FIX4X.xml and simply add the used fields (keeping what is not used by the counterparty but defined in the standard), keeping also the unused messages?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: FYI, I think you just meant the data dictionary xml file, and not "FIXML" (which means something totally different).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen a counterparty supply any FIXML or XSD - we always start with the FIX4X.xml, and tweak to match the counterparty's spec which is usually a PDF.

I've always left in the optional fields if they don't affect my processing, but I can see value in, for example, eliminating bond-related fields on a connection that's certified for equities only so that if bonds start flowing down, you get a reject and know something's wrong.

Comment: I *have* seen a counterparty provide a DD xml file, but we still had to make corrections to it because they were dummies.  Can't trust counterparties to get their own stuff right.

Comment: "Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity."

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Or get them to abide by the FIX protocol, it is laughable sometimes.